# IE: Select dropdown is opening upwards not downwards

Tags: internet-explorer, select

I have a select dropdown at the top of my page (localhost for testing now). In IE it does not drop down, it drops up, going off the page and over the bookmark and address bar of the browser. I have checked the select box in opera, safari, firefox, and chrome, and it works just fine. The only problem is in IE.

There is absolutely nothing fancy about the code it is a simple select dropdown:

```
<select>
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

I am having problems googling this because once I type "down", "up" or "box" in the search field I get all sorts of results that have nothing to do with the the select box. So if anyone here has a better way of searching for this or knows how to handle this I would love some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887742/how-do-you-stop-a-dropdown-menu-from-going-up

Comment: Is there enough space below the dropdown? usually it goes up automatically due to lack of space

Comment: there is an image, would z-index or something else similar do the trick?

Comment: Usually elements below don't matter, what matters is the distance to the bottom of the window. Try moving your select up in the markup

Comment: Put the selectbox at the top of the code, still having issues. Turns out that ie will open the dropdown with the selected option as the middle. So if option 2 is selected, 0 and 1 will be above the select box and 3 will be below the select box...

Comment: When filing issues against IE, it's important to specify the version you're testing against. The SELECT behavior in IE varies greatly between IE9 and later versions.

Comment: IE 8 through 10. I have 10 and am switching between them using browser mode

Comment: Using "Browser mode" in the F12 tools isn't a reliable way to test this behavior; IE10 uses the new-style of SELECT control regardless of what mode you're in.