# How to prevent drop down list goes upwards?

Tags: html, css, list, dropdown, direction

I want to my drop-down list only goes downwards not in both direction

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijl4R.png)

```
<select name="routeNo">
<option value="" disabled selected style="color: rgb(214, 205, 205);">Bus No.</option>
<%**strong text**
while(rs.next())
{%>
    <option><%=rs.getString("routeNo")%></option>
<%}
%>
```

[Check my repository](https://github.com/NishantTheProgrammer/BusManagementSystem)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Drop-downs are rendered by the Browser/OS. You cannot control this type of behaviour using CSS or JavaScript."*

~Diodeus - James MacFarlane

Refer to: [How do you stop a dropdown menu from going up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887742/how-do-you-stop-a-dropdown-menu-from-going-up)